# How to remove a table of N natural numbers and replace with a generative subquery, in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, numbers, subquery, left-join

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE nums (
    num INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO nums VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO nums VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO nums VALUES(2);
```

I use this as the left hand side of LEFT OUTER JOINs to make sure I get a NULL or zero result when I link to tables with missing rows.

How can I generate N numbers (from zero) in a generative subquery, so that I can remove this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to generate a series of values from start to stop, with a step size (default 1) :

> generate_series ( start integer, stop integer [, step integer ] ) →
> setof integer

```
SELECT * 
FROM generate_series(0,2);
```